# Unit and Integration Testing for Google Drive API using C# (Client Library v3)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, google-drive-api, integration-testing

I am writing a small library which uses Google Drive API v3 Client Library for C#.
And for me it involves a lot of pain because I can't use TDD-style for that purpose.

The regular method for doing the job looks something like:

```
internal async Task<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList> ReadFileList(string parentId, string pageToken, int pageSize)
{
    // Define parameters of request.
    var listRequest = this.driveService.Files.List();
    listRequest.PageSize = pageSize;
    listRequest.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and ('" + parentId + "' in parents)";
    listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
    listRequest.PageToken = pageToken;

    // List files.
    return await listRequest.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

For Unit Testing it contains a couple of dependencies (probably it might be refactored using factory method pattern):

1. ListRequest
2. FileList

For Integrating Tests there are much more problems:

1. How should I authenticate such service?
2. Even after authentication it will pollute real Authenticated Drive Account.
3. How to share the tests between other people?
4. Test couldn't pass without an internet connection.

Is there something like "In-Memory" provider for Entity Framework Core?
What can be done to make Google Drives Unit and Integration Tests manageable?

Comment: That is because your code is tightly coupled to the 3rd part SDK. add a layer of abstraction between your code and the 3rd party api and that should allow for more flexibility and mocking code you control.

Comment: This may or may not help https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/b576d21924139902b7163d0441636a20

Comment: @Nikosi Yes, it s a good suggestion. I'd already created a separated layer. But I still have concerns about the underlying one.

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: @zaitsman I use Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. Didn't realized that it may affect something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with Enterprise you're in luck.

Assuming a sample project like so:

1. Installed a nuget package `Google.Apis.Drive.v3`
2. Added a class with the following listing:

This is the actual program

```
 public class Class1
  {
    public async Task<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList> ReadFileList(string parentId, string pageToken, int pageSize)
    {
      // get the service somehow.
      var ds = new DriveService();

      var listRequest = ds.Files.List();
      listRequest.PageSize = pageSize;
      listRequest.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and ('" + parentId + "' in parents)";
      listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
      listRequest.PageToken = pageToken;

      // List files.
      return await listRequest.ExecuteAsync();
    }
  }
```

We can utilize the power of Microsoft Fakes framework to unit test everything here without having any connection to the internet, google drive, accounts etc.

1. Add a Microsoft Test Project (note: just a dll wouldn't work here)
2. In the test project, install the same nuget package.
3. Generate the fakes assemblies for the libraries in which your classes live (in this case, `Google.Apis.Drive.v3` and `Google.Apis`, you are using types from both):
   [image]
4. Write the unit test:

like so

```
  [TestClass]
  public class UnitTest1
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
      using (Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.ShimsContext.Create())
      {
        int? usedPageSize = 0;
        var usedQ = string.Empty;
        var usedFields = string.Empty;
        var usedPageToken = string.Empty;

        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Fakes.ShimFilesResource.ShimListRequest.AllInstances.PageSizeSetNullableOfInt32 =
          (request, i) => usedPageSize = i;
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Fakes.ShimFilesResource.ShimListRequest.AllInstances.QSetString = (request, s) => usedQ = s;
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Fakes.ShimDriveBaseServiceRequest<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList>.AllInstances
          .FieldsSetString = (request, s) => usedFields = s;

        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Fakes.ShimFilesResource.ShimListRequest.AllInstances.PageTokenSetString = (request, s) => usedPageToken = s;
        Google.Apis.Requests.Fakes.ShimClientServiceRequest<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList>.AllInstances
            .ExecuteAsync =
          request =>
            Task.FromResult(
              new FileList
                {
                  ETag = "hello",
                  Files = new List<File> { new File { Name = "imafile" } },
                  IncompleteSearch = false,
                  Kind = "Somekind",
                  NextPageToken = null
                });

        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Fakes.ShimFilesResource.AllInstances.List = resource => (FilesResource.ListRequest)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(FilesResource.ListRequest));
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Fakes.ShimDriveService.Constructor = service => { }; // do not init the class
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Fakes.ShimDriveService.AllInstances.FilesGet = service => (FilesResource)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(FilesResource));

        var target = new Class1();
        var result = target.ReadFileList("parent", "token", 42).Result;

        Assert.AreEqual(42, usedPageSize);
        Assert.AreEqual("mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and ('parent' in parents)", usedQ);
        Assert.AreEqual("nextPageToken, files(id, name)", usedFields);
        Assert.AreEqual("token", usedPageToken);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Files.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("imafile", result.Files[0].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("hello", result.ETag);
        Assert.IsFalse(result.IncompleteSearch.Value);
        Assert.AreEqual("Somekind", result.Kind);
        Assert.IsNull(result.NextPageToken);
      }
    }
  }
```